Exe from Environment Variables file act different in command promp - CLOSED
So i was making an program out of Python that let me quick sending emails. After having it done, I add its path to the User Environment Variable 'Path'.
The folder where my exe file's in
But after calling it from command prompt, it giving me the error of not finding the config file in its directory. I found out that was because calling it that way actually making some temp files and it changes the exe path.
I want to find a smart way to still access my config file without specifically call it by an pre-defined path. Anybody's idea?
EDIT: It make a temp folder in local data/ temp and execute the exe file there.
The error in command prompt
The code that open .config file
The value(below) which was given to open() 

Can you share the relevant code for opening the file?

Would you also share your error message ?

I edited and shared them in the content of the post!

Would you try to print the file path on runtime, just to control where it is? It is amibigious if you're using the relative path, what about the absolute one ?

as it looks like, you are using pyinstaller for the creation of your exe. There are two steps, which you should consider:

(pre-)setting the bundle in your module(package)

try:
    # ATTENTION:
    # The _MEIPASS attribute is used by PyInstaller to point to the
    # base directory where the bundled files are located when the script
    # is run as a bundled executable. It stands for:
    # _MEIPASS  == "My Executable's Install Path And Script's Source."

    # Handles the case where the script runs from bundle
    cfg_dir = Path(getattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"))
    cfg_file = cfg_dir/ "config"
except AttributeError:
    # Fallback in case running from source
    cfg_dir= Path(__file__).absolute()
    cfg_file= cfg_dir / "config"
finally:
    if not cfg_file.exists():
        raise RuntimeError("Something went wrong with the script!")


creating the bundle with pyInstaller


pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "config;config" your_code.py
important: --add-data must be used, otherwise the config won't be
considered and the program will fail fo find them on runtime

This should help as a start point for the creation of your bundle, but would be nice if you provide some more information.
Attention:
The usage of "_MEIPASS" will make your code somewhat brittle, because you won't be able to change directly your config and will need to do the pyinstall everytime, when you change something in your config.
The provided fallback could help you with this problem too.

Thank you for showing me the fallback method! But it doesn't meet my needs. I am going to try putting the config files on popular folder like documents in Windows!

How your executable will know where the config is? The config itself isn't the executable ?

I meant like having config files putting in My Documents or Appdata, etc. which were being use by many programmes I have seen!
